# Using LVM_INSERTITEM and LVM_SETITEM to insert ListItem

Tags: api, listview, vb6

Can I use Win API methods such as LVM_INSERTITEM and LVM_SETITEM for adding items in ListView control?

I want to load listview data fast, I think objListView.ListItems.add is slow for larger amount of rows to be added into the listview.

Currently I use following code to Add ListItems:

```
Dim tmpLI as ListItem
Set tmpLI = ListView1.ListItems.Add text:="Item" & iCounter
tmpLI.SubItems(1) = objRs("StudentCode")
tmpLI.SubItems(2) = objRs("StudentName")
tmpLI.SubItems(3) = objRs("MotherName")
tmpLI.SubItems(4) = objRs("FatherName")
tmpLI.SubItems(5) = objRs("PhoneNo")
etc.
tmpLI.SubItems(15) = objRs("Description")
```

*[iCounter is a Loop Variable, objRs is ADODB Recordset]*

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask] `please write some code` is utterly off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it probably won't speed things up too much.  You will probably find that use of a With block will give you a better result, though.  Like this:

```
With ListView1.ListItems
    .Add text:="Item" & iCounter
    .SubItems(1) = objRs("StudentCode")
    .SubItems(2) = objRs("StudentName")
    .SubItems(3) = objRs("MotherName")
    .SubItems(4) = objRs("FatherName")
    .SubItems(5) = objRs("PhoneNo")
    etc.
    .SubItems(15) = objRs("Description")
End With
```

The reason that this is faster is that you only need to resolve the object reference once, at the top of the With block, instead of once for each line of code.

You might also get noticeable improvement with using objRs.Fields(0), objRs.Fields(1), etc.  The runtime has to resolve the field name string to the offset of the Collection, which is an extra step.  The compiler doesn't know about the database, so it can't do that at compile time.  When you remove the extra step, you remove performance overhead.  Whether it's enough to make a difference might be worth testing.

Comment: Thanks for nicely explaining the things.